# Prevent duplicate records declaratively

Tags: workflow, datetime, field-update, duplicate-management, order-of-execution

Am trying to prevent users from creating duplicate records based on Date and Hour combination from Date/Time field.Since we cannot refer date/time field in Matching rule,so I had move this (Date+Hour)logic to workflow/field update.But Duplicate rule is not evaluating after workflow field update.

[Order of execution](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm) says duplicate rules fire first then workflow field update

Also there is an idea
[Validation Rules and Duplicate Rules Should Fire After a Workflow Field Update](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DjorAAC)

I also tried  making workflow field update (Date+Hour) field as Unique but the problem is we cannot customize error message where as in duplicate rule we can customize error message.

Is there a way to achieve this declaratively?

Comment: If I understand your problem, I'm guessing the answer is no. You're going to have to resort to code.

Comment: apex trigger (before insert/update) to copy Date+Hour into custom field; then duplicate rule on the custom field